# How do I use Qt's example Borderlayout in Qt Designer?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-designer, qlayout

I'm new to Qt and don't grasp Qt Designer's relation to source code fully yet. I implemented [Borderlayout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layouts-borderlayout.html) example and would like to design my UI in Qt Designer using it, but don't know how. I'm using Qt 5.3 and C++.

Comment: @LaszloPapp if it lets me see the layout in the linked page in Qt Designer, then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Designer still does not support custom layout plugins:

[Designer should be able to use custom layout plugins.](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-3109)